# How to put “” and ‘’ in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, special-characters

Say I want to insert that into program.

If I put “” visual studio will just change that to ""

Comment: What you mean by put ? textbox,VS editor ?

Comment: well if I type """" vb.net will simply change the curly quote into a straight quote.

Comment: Try to use ChrW() with right charcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the Unicode code points from the Windows charmap.exe utility.  Tick "advanced" and type "quotation" in the search box.  Producing this code:

```
Public Shared Function QuoteString(ByVal str As String, Optional ByVal doubled As Boolean = True) As String
    If doubled Then
        Return ChrW(&H201C) + str + ChrW(&H201D)
    Else
        Return ChrW(&H2018) + str + ChrW(&H2019)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use `&` for concatenation instead of `+` ? :)

Comment: there is no way to avoid using chrw isn't it? where can I see chrw table?

Comment: I explicitly mentioned that in my answer, use Charmap.exe to see the 'table'.  Or any Unicode chart set.